# HTML Form can't use data inserted by JavaScript (WordPress, NinjaForms)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms

For context: The form is created by the NinjaForms Plugin in a WordPress-powered website.

This JavaScript successfully inserts a value into a required field when the page finishes loading. It does take a few tries to find that `input#insertOrderId` element. When a user submits the form, the field is flagged as empty, even though you can clearly see that it is filled out. If the user manually makes an edit to the field, the form will submit.

I have concluded that the form can't access the value of `input#insertOrderId` when it is inserted by this JavaScript.

Why is this happening? Or, what is happening?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const orderId = urlParams.get('order_id');

    /**
     * re-run querySelector until the element is found
     */
    function pollDOM () {
        let orderIdField = document.querySelector('input#insertOrderId');

        if ( orderIdField === null ) {
            setTimeout(pollDOM, 300);
        } else {
            if ( orderId ) {
                orderIdField.setAttribute('value', orderId);
            }
        }
    }

    pollDOM();

});
```

Comment: Is the form element also added dynamically otherwise it seems weird that you have to poll for its existence?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setAttribute maybe also try [EventTarget.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

E.g.

```js
orderIdField.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))
```

Maybe the code uses the `onchange` handler.
And if you just set the `value` attribute there's no `onchange` event,
so nothing happens.

```js
document.getElementById("unique").onchange = () => {
   document.getElementsByTagName("var")[0].innerText++
}

function setValue () {
   document.getElementById("unique").value = "999999"
}
```

```html
<label for="unique">
   Try editing the form input:
   <input id="unique" />
</label>

<button type="button" onclick="setValue()">
  Set value to "999999"
</button>

<p><code>onchange</code> count: <var>0</var></p>
```